# To know vs Would know

Tags: subjunctive-mood

> Mary: "Does he have any enemies here?"

> Bill: "Not that I know of."

or

> Bill: "Not that I **would** know of."

Is there a difference in meaning between the two answers Bill gives?

Comment: Where have you heard/seen the second version? It doesn't seem at all idiomatic  to me.

Comment: Intuitively, "Not that I know of" is a simple, neutral statement of fact, while "Not that I would know of" is a more nuanced denial, perhaps a bit more defensive, akin to "How would I know?" or "Why are you asking me?" Using "would" indicates that Bill maybe has something to hide, or else is trying to say not just "I don't know" but also "it is impossible for me to know" or "there is no reason for me to know". Compare "I don't know" with "I wouldn't know".

Comment: The second statement is certainly marked as @Stuart says, though in rarefied (think Jeeves) mid-century poshspeak it could just be a register marker. Mind you, Jeeves uses "Indeed sir" to mean "Balderdash" on occasion.